# How can you make an Azure SQL server publicly accessible?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I know you can modify the firewall rules for an Azure SQL Server to allow connections to a specific IP address, but is there a way to specify wildcards to allow for all IP addresses?

Answer (score 3):

Not like SQL wild cards .But you can do like below .

**Example :**

Adding like below allows  all the IPs in range after 49.205

```
49.205.0.0 to 49.205.0.0
```

adding like below allows whole world to access your db.

```
0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0
```

**Note:**
This makes your server **less secure**,as allowed IP addresses feature is also one way to protect database against unauthorized usage

Comment: I'm getting the following message with that rule:  IP range not valid
Adding a rule with range '0.0.0.0' - '0.0.0.0' is the same as turning ON 'Allow access to Azure services' setting. Please use the setting instead.

Comment: What is the "Allow access to Azure services" for?  Does that open up my server to all Azure services or just mine?

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit: it opens up access to your azure services

Answer (score 2):

0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 this will open the firewall completel